# AWK - Delete whole line when inside that line a piece matchs a string

Tags: bash, awk

I have a db.sql full of lines containing sometime the string *_wc_session_*

```
(26680, '_wc_session_expires_120f486fe21c9ae4ce247c04f3b009f9', '1445934089', 'no'),
(26682, '_wc_session_expires_73516b532380c28690a4437d20967e03', '1445934114', 'no'),
(26683, '_wc_session_1a71c566970b07ac2b48c5da4e0d43bf', 'a:21:{s:4:"cart";s:305:"a:1:{s:32:"7fe1f8abaad094e0b5cb1b01d712f708";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:459;s:12:"variation_id";s:0:"";s:9:"variation";a:0:{}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";d:6;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:6;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}}";s:15:"applied_coupons";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:23:"coupon_discount_amounts";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:27:"coupon_discount_tax_amounts";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:21:"removed_cart_contents";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:19:"cart_contents_total";d:6;s:20:"cart_contents_weight";i:0;s:19:"cart_contents_count";i:1;s:5:"total";i:0;s:8:"subtotal";i:6;s:15:"subtotal_ex_tax";i:6;s:9:"tax_total";i:0;s:5:"taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"shipping_taxes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:13:"discount_cart";i:0;s:17:"discount_cart_tax";i:0;s:14:"shipping_total";i:0;s:18:"shipping_tax_total";i:0;s:9:"fee_total";i:0;s:4:"fees";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:10:"wc_notices";s:205:"a:1:{s:7:"success";a:1:{i:0;s:166:"<a href="http://bdebarcelona.cat/carrito/" class="button wc-forward">Ver carrito</a> Se ha añadido &quot;Incienso Gaudí Lavanda&quot; con éxito a tu carrito.";}}";}', 'no'),
```

I'd like to remove those whole lines with AWK when *_wc_session_* is within. I mean the whole line like:

```
(26682, '_wc_session_expires_73516b532380c28690a4437d20967e03', '1445934114', 'no'),
```

So far I've found the right REGEX that select the whole line 
 when "*_wc_session_*" is found

```
(^\(.*_wc_session_.*\)\,)
```

but we I try to run

```
awk '!(^\(.*_wc_session_.*\)\,)' db.sql > temp.sql
```

I get

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ^
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you expect that command to work? Did you make any effort to learn awk syntax?

Comment: I did and beacuse I don't use awk so much I forgot to add / at the begin and the end of the regex.. '!/(^\(.*_wc_session_.*\)\,)/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake on the input Regex, the right one is

```
'!/(^(.*wc_session.*)\,)/'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're set on `awk`:

```
awk '!/_wc_session/' db.sql
```

You may also you `sed -i` to write output "inplace" (in the input file):

```
sed -i '/_wc_session/d' db.sql
```

Edit:

A more precise approach with `awk` would be to use the inherent `,` from your file as delimiter and only check column 2 for the respective pattern. This approach is useful in case the pattern would be in a different column and that line should not be removed.

```
awk -F',' '$2 !~ "_wc_session" {print $0}' db.sql
```

Comment: I meant the whole line (26682, '_wc_session_expires_73516b532380c28690a4437d20967e03', '1445934114', 'no'),

Answer (score 2):

With simple `grep` following may help you in same and should do the trick.

```
grep -v "(26682, '_wc_session_expires_73516b532380c28690a4437d20967e03', '1445934114', 'no')"   Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** If you want to remove the lines which have only string `_wc_session_expires_` in any line then following may help you in same.

```
grep -v "_wc_session_expires_"   Input_file
```

Comment: I meant the whole line     (26682, '_wc_session_expires_73516b532380c28690a4437d20967e03', '1445934114', 'no'),

Comment: @GiacomoScarpino, please check my edited solution now with `grep` it worked fine for me, kindly do let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Sorry man... I meant I'd like to remove the line, the whole line, when if find *_wc_session* in that line.. I hope I made myself clear..

Comment: @GiacomoScarpino, please check my EDIT command which will remove all lines which have `_wc_session_expires_` string in any line, let me know if you are good with it?